# Book about a girl who lives in an underground community to escape the zombie outbreak

Tags: story-identification, books, choose-your-own-adventure, underground-civilization, zombie-apocalypse

Im looking for this online choices book and have been for a while. I used to read it back in 2016. It’s about a girl who lives in an underground community with her family. Their ancestors moved them underground to escape the zombie outbreak and it was believed that the surface was unsafe for human life. Once the underground children made it to Highschool they were taken from homeschooling and put into a public one. She starts everyday with a walk to the bus stop with her guy best friend (also her neighbor that she has known since birth). She meets this boy (12th grader) and they get sent on a mission topside. The 3 of them are determined to find out how to stop the outbreak and bring their people back from their underground homes. The only other thing I remember is in their attempt to get away from the zombies they hide in an arcade and you can either hide with the best friend (who is in love with her) or the other guy (that she is in love with) and if you choose the other guy y'all hide in a ball pit and the girl is the sergeants daughter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s called ***[Zombie High](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/59346984-zombie-high)*** (2013) by Sam Landstrom and Erin Foster Hartley, I'm pretty sure. I used to love that one too! Sadly, I think you can only get it on Google Play.

> It’s thirteen years into the zombie apocalypse, and civilization has moved underground. You play Jane Valentine, a high school freshman with two goals: make dreamy Tommy Fernando fall in love with her and kick as much zombie butt as possible. It’s up to you whether she becomes the most popular zombie fighter in school or is left to wander the halls a nasty fecto.